# React Native - GPS enabled but still returns disabled to my console log?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using package `react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box`. So how my App should flow is if the GPS Enabled I will return `this.setState({locationEnabled: true})` then navigate to my Next Screen which is `AuthScreen`. Otherwise, if the GPS is disabled before the App starts, it will shows a modal to enable GPS then navigate to the `AuthScreen`.

My problem is, before the App starts the GPS already enabled or disabled, the modal still shows to enabled the GPS (even it is already enabled) then I expect to navigate to the `AuthScreen` because the GPS is already enabled but no. Even the GPS is enabled or disabled, it returns "disabled" to my console log. This package returns this `success => {alreadyEnabled: false, enabled: true, status: "enabled"}` in `then` statement. How do I use this to make my App flow perfectly?

Here's a weird thing. Yesterday, my App doesn't behave or flow like this. I didn't change any codes yesterday and today I open my App now my App behaves like this. Please help me thank you!

Here's the URL: https://github.com/webyonet/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box

Here are my codes:

```
enableLocation = () => {
    LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
        message: "<h2 style='color: #0af13e'>Use Location ?</h2>This app wants to change your device settings:<br/><br/>Use GPS, Wi-Fi, and cell network for location<br/><br/><a href='#'>Learn more</a>",
        ok: "YES",
        cancel: "NO",
        enableHighAccuracy: true, // true => GPS AND NETWORK PROVIDER, false => GPS OR NETWORK PROVIDER
        showDialog: true, // false => Opens the Location access page directly
        openLocationServices: true, // false => Directly catch method is called if location services are turned off
        preventOutSideTouch: false, // true => To prevent the location services window from closing when it is clicked outside
        preventBackClick: false, // true => To prevent the location services popup from closing when it is clicked back button
        providerListener: false // true ==> Trigger locationProviderStatusChange listener when the location state changes
    }).then((success) => {
        this.setState({
           locationEnabled: true
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        // alert(error.message);
    });

};

render() {

    if(!this.state.locationEnabled) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            </View>
        )
    } else {
        return <AuthScreen/>
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the result you are getting from .then or .catch?

Comment: you can try the GoeLocation Package provided by Facebook   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation

Comment: @RizwanAhmedShivalli is there a function there to prompt user to enable GPS?

Comment: as far as i know, yes it will automatically ask user to enable the gps for the session if it is not On

Comment: Okay I'll try in then

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara I get `[Error.disabled]` from .catch